# Django: ForeignKey choices with limit_choices_to not distinct in Admin

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have the following models in Django 1.3:

```
class A(models.Model):
    # fields

class RelatedToA(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(
        A, 
        related_name="related_set"
    )
    # fields

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(
        A,
        limit_choices_to={'related_set__isnull'=False}
    )
```

Now in ModelAdmin for B, there are multiple entries of every instance of A in the dropdown.
Is there a way to get the choices distinct on model level?

Comment: It's a [known bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11707)

Comment: good answer. I have upvoted you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do that with formfield_for_foreignkey you could pass a custom query to be evaluated for the foreign key values in the drop down menu.
See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/ for formfield_for_foreignkey.

Answer (score 0):

**Retrieve specific values from a foreign key Table for Django admin as well as anywhere in our project. This is very powerful option in Django ORM. You can try this. Best of luck.**

```
class A(models.Model):
    """ 
        Purpose: create model A
    """

    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=256)
    short_code = models.CharField('shortcode of geo area', max_length=16, null=True, blank=True) 

    def __str__(self):

        return f'{self.name}/{self.short_code}'

    def __name__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "A detail"
        verbose_name_plural = "A details"

class B(models.Model):
    """ 
        Purpose: create B table
    """

    name = models.CharField('organization name', max_length=128)
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='a_related_info', null=False, limit_choices_to={'name': 'James Bond', 'short_code': 007})  

    def __str__(self):

        return f'{self.name}/{self.model_a.name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "B Detail"
        verbose_name_plural = "B Details"
```